# what type is the graph reduced from k-regular hypergraph?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, approximation

[image] 
A hypergraph $H = (V,E)$ consists of a set $V = \{v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n\}$ of vertices and a set $E = \{e_1, e_2, \cdots , e_m\}$ of edges, each being a subset of $V$. If each $|V| = 2$, H is a general graph.

The degree $d(v)$ of a vertex v is the number of edges that contain it. H is **k-regular** if every vertex has the same degree k.

**My question is: If we reduce a k-regular hypergraph to a general graph by replacing each edge with a clique, then the resulted general graph is not of bounded degree (the degree of a vertex can be up to n-1 where n is the total number of vertices). However I think it must be a special type of graph, I cannot figure out which type it is.**

If you can help me out here I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What you call *bounded* is usually called *regular*. A bounded-degree graph is just a graph in which all degrees are bounded by some $k$ (this  definition only makes sense for a *family* of graphs, say all valid inputs to some algorithm).

Comment: Yuval, Thanks! In my application problem, the hypergraph $H$ is dual of another k-uniform hypergraph hence $H$ is k-regular, I am thinking reducing it to general graph however it lost the nice bounded degree property

Comment: It looks like the average degree of general graph is bounded?